# XML to Datatable conversion fails

Tags: asp.net, xml, datatable

I want to convert an XML string to Datatable.String is like this

```
<TextstringArray>
    <values>
        <value>athul</value>
        <value>aks@phases.dk</value>
        <value>1</value>
    </values>
    <values>
        <value>arun</value>
        <value>am@phases.dk</value>
        <value>1</value>
    </values>
    <values>
        <value>ajmal</value>
        <value>am@phases.dk</value>
        <value>1</value>
    </values>
</TextstringArray>
```

I have tried something like this

```
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(invitations);
DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);
```

But the datatset comes out with wrongly formatted data.
like all value elements are coming in single column.I want them in three columns.one for first and so on.(Xml is getting in to table but not the xml structure)

[image]

Comment: In what way is the data wrongly formatted? (What are you getting? What did you expect?)

Comment: What is wrong in your format?

Comment: Have you noticed that there are actually 2 DataTables inside the DataSet?

Comment: @Richard all the <value> elements comes in same column

Comment: @AlexFilipovici:yes actually its also a problem.value elements in one column and values in another

Comment: Please expand the question with that information describing the problem. (A short correct recreate would also be a good idea.) The more you do to make answering the question easier the more likely you are to get a useful answer.

Comment: @MitchWheat:the link you gave me is the one i referred to do this much.I have updated the question.Please take a look.

Comment: @Richard:I have updated the question please take a look at it.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal, the XML should have the following structure:

```
<TextstringArray>
    <values>
        <value1>athul</value1>
        <value2>aks@phases.dk</value2>
        <value3>1</value3>
    </values>
    <values>
        <value1>arun</value1>
        <value2>am@phases.dk</value2>
        <value3>1</value3>
    </values>
    <values>
        <value1>ajmal</value1>
        <value2>am@phases.dk</value2>
        <value3>1</value3>
    </values>
</TextstringArray>
```

This will produce one single datatable, where each `values` element will be the source of a data row, while each child element of it (`value1`,`value2` etc) will be read as a column.

A workaround would be:

```
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(invitations));
DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

var valueIdsDatatable = theDataSet.Tables[0];
var valueDatatable = theDataSet.Tables[1];

// detect the maximum number of columns
var maxColumns = valueDatatable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(i => i["values_Id"]).Max(i => i.Count());

// create the result DataTable
var resultDataTable = new DataTable();

// add dynamically the columns
for (int i = 0; i < maxColumns; i++)
{
    resultDataTable.Columns.Add("property" + i);
}

// add the rows
foreach (DataRow valueId in valueIdsDatatable.Rows)
{
    var newRow = resultDataTable.NewRow();
    var currentRows = valueDatatable.Select("values_id = " + valueId[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < currentRows.Length; i++)
    {
        newRow[i] = currentRows[i][0];
    }
    resultDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

// TODO: use the resultDataTable
```

Comment: its impossible for me to change the way xml comes, its from an external api.Is there any other way?

Comment: @Arun I've posted one option in my answer. Note that this will be brittle and will not deal well with changes to the XML format. However, any proposed solution will have that issue.

Comment: @RB, _... any proposed solution will have that issue_. Not really, as long as you don't make any assumptions about the number or the order of the `value` children. During serialization, order of processing is not guaranteed, unless attributes are used on the class representation to control it.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici If you don't make assumptions about the number or order of the `value` children you won't have a clue what data each one represents, so you will be left with an arbitrary series of strings.

Comment: Yes, but the arbitrary part is intended since the XML source.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some LINQy goodness to group and project into a new data-structure.

Note that the following code expects there to be exactly 3 values in every group, and relies on the input being consistent. If this is not the case you will need to adapt it to your environment.

```
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(invitations);
DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);

// Get the table we are interested in.
var dt = theDataSet.Tables["value"];

// Group by the "values_Id" field. This is what logically 
// relates each <value>.
// Then, project out a new type, assuming that the first row 
// holds the username, the second holds the email address,
// and the third holds "some thing else".
var rows = dt.Rows.
    Cast<DataRow>().
    GroupBy(dr => dr["values_Id"]).
    Select(row => 
        new 
        {
            RowId = row.Key,
            UserName = row.ElementAt(0)["value_Text"],
            UserEmail = row.ElementAt(1)["value_Text"],
            UserOtherValue = row.ElementAt(2)["value_Text"]
        });

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Row " + row.RowId);
    Console.WriteLine("    UserName: " + row.UserName);
    Console.WriteLine("    Email: " + row.UserEmail);
    Console.WriteLine("    OtherValue: " + row.UserOtherValue);
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
Row 0
    UserName: athul
    Email: aks@phases.dk
    OtherValue: 1
Row 1
    UserName: arun
    Email: am@phases.dk
    OtherValue: 1
Row 2
    UserName: ajmal
    Email: am@phases.dk
    OtherValue: 1
```